# stringValue of NSDictionary objectForKey runtime error

Tags: casting, nsstring, nsdictionary

So I have the following code that causes a runtime error in XCode

```
NSString* temp = [[param objectforkey@"firstParam"] stringValue];
int tempNum = [[param objectforkey@"secondParam"] intValue];
```

param loads from a plist.  firstParam is as string, secondParam is a number

First line crashes the program.

Now what's interesting is it works if I do a hard caste i.e:

```
NSString* temp = (NSString*)[param objectforkey@"firstParam"];
int tempNum = [[param objectforkey@"secondParam"] intValue];
```

Just wondering why the id would have inconsistent implementation in that I have to use intValue to cast to int, but have to do hard cast to get NSString?  Why not stringValue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first call to `objectForKey` returns an object which is an `NSString`.  `NSString` doesn't have a `stringValue` method which is why a runtime error is generated.  It doesn't make sense to get the `stringValue` of something that is already a string.

The second call to `objectForKey` returns an `NSNumber`. `NSNumber` does have an `intValue` method so it doesn't cause an error.

In the second case you are changing the type of the returned value from `NSNumber` to `int`.  In the first case the object returned is already an `NSString` and there is no point trying to get the `stringValue` of a string.

Comment: Hmm, and what when I can not be sure that the returned value is a `NSString`? I thaugth `stringValue` would be equivalent to java's `toString`  and thus always avaliable.

Comment: If you aren't sure what type of object you are retrieving from your collection you will have to inspect the object to see what type it is before calling the appropriate method(s).

Answer (score 6):

The call `[param objectforkey@"firstParam"]` DOES return a NSString, so there's no need to call stringValue. Furthermore, NSString does not have a method called "stringValue", so that's the source of your problem.

Just call this: `NSString *temp = (NSString *)[param objectForKey:@"firstParam"];`

Also note that the selector is **objectForKey:**, not *objectforkey:* (capitalization matters).

And, answering your question, NSNumber is a class, so any object is not an "int", but a NSNumber pointer. intValue returns an actual "int", as floatValue returns a "float" (NSNumber can represent any type of number). In the case of the NSString that's not necessary, because there is only one type of NSString (there is, though, a method for returning a `const char *`, and that would be used like `char *string = [[param objectForKey:@"firstParam"] cString];`... not very useful for Objective-C apps anyway).

Comment: Thanks Alejandro.  Appreciate the added explanation for cString.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you call a web service that returns JSON

Then you process data

```
 NSDictionary *json_response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 error:NULL];
```

now you try something like this

```
 NSString *name = [[object objectForKey:@"Name"] stringValue];
```

then you get the error....

As [mttrb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320303/mttrb) mentions you get the error because of stringValue, objectForKey default return value is String so a potential fix in this case would be:

```
NSString *name = [object objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

Hope this hints some one!

Answer (score 1):

If you can not be sure that the returned value is a `NSString` you should do this:

```
id value = [param objectForKey@"firstParam"];

if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   NSString *temp = (NSString *)id;
   //Handle string
}
else {
  //Handle other case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Completing the answer of @Torge, I add my solution to get always an NSString from objectForKey method:

```
NSObject * value = [param objectForKey@"firstParam"];
NSString *stringValue;
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   //Handle string
   stringValue = (NSString *)value;

}
else if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
    //Handle NSNumber
    stringValue = [((NSNumber *) value) stringValue];

}
else {
    //Handle other case
}
```